# How can I resolve my TypeScript error: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: typescript

I am using the Sweet Alert library:

```
https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/
```

and I am trying to use the following code from the site:

```
swal({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
  cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
  confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
  cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
  buttonsStyling: false
}).then(function () {
  swal(
    'Deleted!',
    'Your file has been deleted.',
    'success'
  )
}, function (dismiss) {
  // dismiss can be 'cancel', 'overlay',
  // 'close', and 'timer'
  if (dismiss === 'cancel') {
    swal(
      'Cancelled',
      'Your imaginary file is safe :)',
      'error'
    )
  }
})
```

I have installed types by running:

```
npm install --save @types/sweetalert
```

but I am still getting an error message in relation to the use of 'then':

```
error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your type definition file and your library do not add up. You've pulled in `@types/sweetalert`, which is the .d.ts file for `https://sweetalert.js.org/`, instead of `https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/`.

Looking at the repository for SweetAlert2, it includes [type definitions](https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2/blob/master/sweetalert2.d.ts) in the same npm package as the library.